# Failed to find the component of a local gem component

Tags: voltrb

I'm making a volt component called volt-date_time_picker. When I use the component from a simple app, I obtain this error:

```
RuntimeError at /
Unable to find component 'font_awesome', make sure the gem is included in your Gemfile
```

This is the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'volt-font_awesome'

# Specify your gem's dependencies in volt-date_time_picker.gemspec
gemspec
```

This is my dependencies.rb:

```
# Component dependencies

component 'font_awesome'
```

I have a simple app that uses this component, and this is in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'volt-date_time_picker', '0.1.0', :path => '/home/miguel/development/ruby/lib/volt-date_time_picker'
```

This is in my dependencies.rb:

```
component 'date_time_picker'
```

(Note: If I include the gem font_awesome in the Gemfile of the app then it works.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in file gemspec solves the problem:

```
spec.add_dependency "volt-font_awesome"
```

Gemfile should be like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Specify your gem's dependencies in volt-date_time_picker.gemspec
gemspec
```